# Oracle APEX Application Builder: Search for specific employee and return their name, salary & department in an hard coded textfield

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to the Oracle APEX AB and currently trying to implement a specific mask that we need for work:
We have a table in our SQL-Database for employees. It looks like the following:

```
| staff_id | name | salary | department_id|
```

The goal is to have an own input mask, where I have to write down the staff_id, e.g. 100600.
Then I click a submit button and the output is created dynamically in the same mask as a text that consists the following (column value in brackets):
"Employee [name] has a salary of [salary] € and works in department [department_id].

This scenario is visualized in the following picture:

[image]

My problem now is that I don't understand the following things:

- Which element do I need to use in the page designer as an input?
  (Currently I am trying it with a numberfield)
- How can I extract the value out of this numberfield and use it into
  an sql query for the output text.
- Third: How can I create a hard coded textfield that will only appear
  after submitting with columns that dynamically adjust to the
  Input-ID?

So the workflow should be something like:
**First**: Insert staff_id into numb_field and submit
**Second**: SELECT name, salary, department_id FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE STAFF_ID = numb_field_value
**Third**: Put the received values name, salary, department_id in a hardcoded text as the gap fillers and give it as an output on the screen.

Thank you for your help! :)

Visualization of the Input and Output of the procedure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how:

- create Number datatype item, let's call it P72_STAFF_ID
- create a button; let it Submit the page
- create a **display only** item with no label (so that it is "invisible")
- create a process which runs PL/SQL code:

  ```
  select 'Employee ' || name || ' has a salary of ' || salary ||
         ' € and works in department ' || department_id
  into :P72_INFO
  from employees
  where staff_id = :P72_STAFF_ID;
  ```

Run the page, enter employee's ID and hit the button. You'll see something like this:

[image]